# How to make font-awesome inline with div

Tags: html, font-awesome

How to make font-awesome inline with div?

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
            <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i></span>
            <marquee>Lorem..</marquee>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a flexbox to align both items. Be aware that `<marquee>` is [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee).

```css
div[role="alert"] {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
      <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i></span>
      <marquee>Lorem..</marquee>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with CSS the following to align in right next to your text.

```
display: inline;
```

Comment: I doing this and nothing happen. `<span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-warning" style="display: inline"></i></span>`